# Reversible function where the output contains all the information about the input

Tags: matrix-calculus, cryptography

I don't know the name of this problem and maybe there is already a solution for it. I am also NOT a mathematician.

I've some numerical input which comes in the form of vector or string such as "1.2.3". I can break those vectors/string down into the natural numbers 1, 2 and 3.

Assume I've N strings. I want to find a function `f(string_1...string_n) = output`

there must be a biunivocal relationship between the input and the output, meaning from the output have enough information to go back to the original input. The information domain of the output should be big enough so that there are no collisions. Each vector can go from 0.0.0 to 999999999.999999999.999999999

**example:**

assume 2 strings in input  1.2.3 and 4.5.6

I've been thinking of multiplication for example:

(1)(4)=4

(2)(5)=10

(3)(6)=18

This doesn't work because 4 can be also the result of 2*2
Maybe the solution is in some kind of invertible cipher where the key is the input itself?
Any idea is welcome, thank you

Comment: The natural way would be to concatenate your strings, padding withs zeros as necessary. So $f(1,2,3) = 000000001000000002000000003$.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. The issue is that I could have 20 to 100 vectors thus making the padded string very long. For a machine probably it wouldn't be a problem but it would be if the string has to be printed on a document for a human for example.

Would it make sense to compress it to remove the padding?  Also i am not sure how the padding solves the reversibility

Comment: It sounds like you're going to end up with some very long strings. The reason for the padding is that otherwise you get ambiguous results: if $f(a,b,c) = 12345$, then what are $a,b,c$? Maybe $(123,4,5)$? Or $(1,23,45)$? As for compression: with any compression algorithm, either it will be lossy (i.e., you will lose information, making the input impossible to reconstruct exactly), or it will be such that some outputs are in fact longer than the inputs. This is an application of the pigeonhole principle. As a simple example, suppose you have just two inputs, each from $0$ to $9$...

Comment: (cont'd) That gives you $100$ possible inputs, from $(0,0)$ up to $(9,9)$. The natural way to encode these is by concatenation, so $(4,3) \to 43$, for example. You can't ask for better than that. It might help to add some context or elaborate on the purpose of this. For example, is it a *strict* requirement that there be no collisions, or do you just want a very low probability of collisions? What about using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)?

Comment: For further reading, you might be interested in [lossless compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression).